# Statically compiling QWebKit 4.6.2

Tags: qt, webkit, linker, static-libraries, static-linking

I tried to compile Qt+Webkit statically with MS VS 2008 and this worked.

```
C:\Qt\4.6.2>configure -release -static -opensource -no-fast -no-exceptions -no-accessibility -no-rtti -no-stl -no-opengl -no-openvg -no-incredibuild-xge -no-style-plastique -no-style-cleanlooks -no-style-motif -no-style-cde -no-style-windowsce -no-style-windowsmobile -no-style-s60 -no-gif -no-libpng -no-libtiff -no-libjpeg -no-libmng -no-qt3support -no-mmx -no-3dnow -no-sse -no-sse2 -no-iwmmxt -no-openssl -no-dbus -platform win32-msvc2008 -arch windows -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-multimedia -no-audio-backend -no-script -no-scripttools -webkit -no-declarative
```

However, I get these errors whenever building a project that links statically to QWebKit:

```
1> Creating library C:\Users\Geeko\Desktop\Qt\TestQ\Release\TestQ.lib and object C:\Users\Geeko\Desktop\Qt\TestQ\Release\TestQ.exp
1>QtWebKit.lib(PluginPackageWin.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _VerQueryValueW@16 referenced in function "class WebCore::String __cdecl WebCore::getVersionInfo(void * const,class WebCore::String const &)" (?getVersionInfo@WebCore@@YA?AVString@1@QAXABV21@@Z)
1>QtWebKit.lib(PluginPackageWin.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GetFileVersionInfoW@16 referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall WebCore::PluginPackage::fetchInfo(void)" (?fetchInfo@PluginPackage@WebCore@@AAE_NXZ)
1>QtWebKit.lib(PluginPackageWin.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GetFileVersionInfoSizeW@8 referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall WebCore::PluginPackage::fetchInfo(void)" (?fetchInfo@PluginPackage@WebCore@@AAE_NXZ)
1>QtWebKit.lib(PluginDatabaseWin.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _imp_PathRemoveFileSpecW@4 referenced in function "class WebCore::String __cdecl WebCore::safariPluginsDirectory(void)" (?safariPluginsDirectory@WebCore@@YA?AVString@1@XZ)
1>QtWebKit.lib(PluginDatabaseWin.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _imp_SHGetValueW@24 referenced in function "void __cdecl WebCore::addWindowsMediaPlayerPluginDirectory(class WTF::Vector &)" (?addWindowsMediaPlayerPluginDirectory@WebCore@@YAXAAV?$Vector@VString@WebCore@@$0A@@WTF@@@Z)
1>QtWebKit.lib(PluginDatabaseWin.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _imp_PathCombineW@12 referenced in function "void __cdecl WebCore::addMacromediaPluginDirectories(class WTF::Vector &)" (?addMacromediaPluginDirectories@WebCore@@YAXAAV?$Vector@VString@WebCore@@$0A@@WTF@@@Z)
1>C:\Users\Geeko\Desktop\Qt\TestQ\Release\TestQ.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals
```

Do I need to check something in the Qt project options? I have QtCore, QtGui, Network and WebKit checked.

Comment: Come on gurus ! no answers nor comments !!

Comment: Do I need to include the multimedia/Phonon modules or gif/jpeg/...etc libraries when configuring Qt for compilation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you need to link in the windows .lib files for each of the missing functions:

VerQueryValue,GetFileVersionInfo -> version.lib

GetFileVersionInfoSize -> Coredll.lib

PathRemoveFileSpec, SHGetValue, PathCombine -> shlwapi.lib

If you are using qmake, you add:
LIBS += -lversion -lCoredll -lshlwapi

Otherwise: From the Project menu, choose Properties.  Open Configuration Properties->Linker->Input.  In the Additional Dependencies field, add version.lib, Coredll.lib and shlwapi.lib

Comment: Actually I only did it for version.lib & shlwapi.lib and it worked! Though, you actually go to Librarian instead of Linker configuration. However, one thing did NOT work: images/videos do not show in the web control ?!

Comment: @geeko: it sounds like Qt isn't loading plugins.  Since you are statically compiling Qt, you need to do some extra steps to get the static plugins to work.  See the Qt docs on static plugins:
http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/plugins-howto.html#static-plugins

Comment: I'm actually using MSVC2008, so is there a way without going through .pro files ?